# WP Query Relations / Compare

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, query, search, query-posts

I am trying to get the search query to use an 'OR' for these arguments.  It is currently using 'AND' which I can not figure out how to change.

I thought the line:

> $args['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'OR');

would do it, but that is not working.

```
if ($search != '') {    
        $args = array(

            's' => $search,

            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,

            'paged' => $paged,

            'post_type' => 'property',

            'post_status' => 'publish'

        );
    }else{
        $args = array(

            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,

            'paged' => $paged,

            'post_type' => 'property',

            'post_status' => 'publish'

        );
    }


 //Custom Searches

        $search_array = get_search_array($search);
        $compare = 'REGEXP';

        $search_array = implode("|", $search_array);


        $args['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'OR');


        array_push($args['meta_query'],

            array('relation' => 'OR', 

                array(

                'key'     => 'property_address',

                'value'   => $search_array,

                'compare' => $compare

                ),

                array(

                'key'     => 'property_city',

                'value'   => $search_array,

                'compare' => $compare

                ),

                array(

                'key'     => 'property_state',

                'value'   => $search_array,

                'compare' => $compare

                ),

                array(

                'key'     => 'property_zip',

                'value'   => $search_array,

                'compare' => $compare

                ),

                array(

                'key'     => 'mlnumber',

                'value'   => $search_array,

                'compare' => $compare

                ),

                array(

                'key'     => 'marketing_remarks',

                'value'   => $search,

                'compare' => 'LIKE'

                )

            )

        );
```

Unfortunately, I keep ending up with this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%201701057%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%201701057%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%201701057%')))  AND ( 
  ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_address' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_city' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_state' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_zip' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'mlnumber' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'marketing_remarks' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%201701057%' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'property' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%201701057%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1000"
```

When I would like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%201701057%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%201701057%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%201701057%')))  **OR** ( 
  ( 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_address' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_city' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_state' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'property_zip' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'mlnumber' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value REGEXP '201701057' ) 
    OR 
    ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'marketing_remarks' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%201701057%' )
  )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'property' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%201701057%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 1000"
```

Comment: Relation is between meta query arguments, you can't OR the whole meta query.

Comment: OK. But I obviously don't understand where I am doing that or doing it  incorrectly.  How do I change that 'AND' to an 'OR'?

Comment: That AND is not controlled by meta query arguments, you can't change that without a direct SQL filter.

Comment: OK got ya.  Well, that's no good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the context of where the code in your question is being used.  Is it something like the following:

```
$args = array (
    's' => '201701057',
    'meta_query' => array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array (
            'key' => 'property_address',
            ...
            ),
        array (
            'key' => 'property_city',
            ...
            ),
        ...
        ),
    ) ;
$query = new WP_Query ($args) ;
```

If so, then you should be able to hook into [get_meta_sql](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_meta_sql/) as follows:

```
add_filter ('get_meta_sql', 'wpse_get_meta_sql_OR', 10, 6) ;

function
wpse_get_meta_sql_OR ($sql, $queries, $type, $primary_table, $primary_id_column, $context)
{
    $sql['where'] = preg_replace ('/^(\s*)AND/', "$1OR", $sql['where']) ;

    return ($sql) ;
}
```

### Caveat

As is, the `wpse_get_meta_sql_OR()` func above is **NOT** intended to be used in general purpose code...because you *MIGHT* not want to `OR` the `meta_query` if there were other than the `'s' => '...'` arg to WP_Query...but it certainly produces your desired SQL **IF** `'s' => '...'` is the *ONLY* other arg to WP_Query than the `meta_query'.